# OrientDB Network Binary Protocol - What is returned when creating a CLASS?

Tags: orientdb, orientdb2.2

What is the meaning of the last two bytes of output (one part of the wrapped record, one not) when creating a class?

I issued the command "CREATE CLASS Foo EXTENDS V".  This is the output (annotated with my understanding of the the protocol):

```
Writing byte (1 byte): 0 [OChannelBinaryServer] # success
Writing int (4 bytes): 43 [OChannelBinaryServer] # session id 43
Writing byte (1 byte): 119 [OChannelBinaryServer] # w - this is a wrapped record
Writing short (2 bytes): 0 [OChannelBinaryServer] # this is a full record
Writing byte (1 byte): 100 [OChannelBinaryServer] # d - record is a document
Writing short (2 bytes): -1 [OChannelBinaryServer] # cluster id null
Writing long (8 bytes): -1 [OChannelBinaryServer] # cluster position null
Writing int (4 bytes): 0 [OChannelBinaryServer] # version 0
Writing bytes (4+16=20 bytes): [0, 0, 12, 114, 101, 115, 117, 108, 116, 0, 0, 0,
  15, 1, 0, 84] [OChannelBinaryServer] # the record, what is 84?
Writing byte (1 byte): 0 [OChannelBinaryServer] # what is this?
```

The record itself decodes to a field named "result".  The value of result is an integer, encoded as a varint 84 which decodes to 42.  Then there is a trailing byte of 0.

What does the result value of 42 mean?
What does the trailing 0 mean?

Please note that I'm on protocol version 36.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The number returned from CREATE CLASS is the number of classes in the database. As for the 0 at the end, I have no idea.

Scott